# Laravel Inertia JS spoofing out Eloquent data. Setting app environment to production or 'Vite(npm) Build' doesn't help. Is there any fixes?

Tags: laravel, vite, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

Inertia route is publishing all the routes, components, Eloquent data even in production environment. How to prevent publishing backend stuff?

[image]

Comment: You're not publishing backend stuff. You're publishing configuration for the frontend. Jetstream is providing you components that require configuration; this is provided by Inertia through the method you see in the image. Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: I don't want people to so see backend configuration in frontend. Here the Complete user model  is published within configuration. I don't see why that's useful for me.

Comment: It's not useful for you. It's useful for the frontend that was built to need that data to function. Whats the issue that the end user see's this? It's there data. Ultimately, if you want to remove it then you'll need to write your own method for sharing this data to the frontend and/or write your own components. On a related note, if not this method then how will you share user data to the frontend?